# Is it possible to make apt skip unsigned repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, steam, repository

My situation is a bit unique (maybe)
I can't do an `apt update` or `upgrade` while at school because Steam is blocked and `apt` is unable to get the key to confirm that the ppa is signed (despite the fact that even if it could get the key, it'd fail to connect) 
Is there a way to make apt skip these repositories (those which aren't signed) instead of halting the entire update process?  That way, repos which are secured can be updated and repos which aren't will be skipped?